# Drupal: Fivestar Block with voting axis

Tags: drupal, drupal-fivestar

I'm using fivestar 1.19 with voting axis. I believe the default fivestar block/fivestar function uses only the default 'vote' tag.

> fivestar_widget_form($node)

I need to pass my custom fivestar tag to the function.

Attempting to follow the answer below:
For me $object is $node.

```
  <?php 
function custom_fivestar_widget ($object) {
  global $user;

  $star_display = variable_get('fivestar_style_'. $object->type, 'average');
  $text_display = variable_get('fivestar_text_'. $object->type, 'dual');

  if ($star_display == 'average' && ($text_display == 'average' || $text_display == 'none')) {
    // Save a query and don't retrieve the user vote unnecessarily.
    $votes = fivestar_get_votes($object->type, $object->nid, 'score', 0);
  }
  else {
    $votes = fivestar_get_votes($object->type, $object->nid);
  }

  $values = array(
    'user' => isset($votes['user']['value']) ? $votes['user']['value'] : 0,
    'average' => isset($votes['average']['value']) ? $votes['average']['value'] : 0,
    'count' => isset($votes['count']['value']) ? $votes['count']['value'] : 0,
  );

  $settings = array(
    'stars' => variable_get('fivestar_stars_'. $object->type, 10),
    'allow_clear' => variable_get('fivestar_unvote_'. $object->type, FALSE),
    'style' => $star_display,
    'text' => $text_display,
    'content_type' => $object->type,
    'content_id' => $object->nid,
    'tag' => 'score',
    'autosubmit' => TRUE,
    'title' => variable_get('fivestar_title_'. $object->type, 1) ? NULL : FALSE,
    'feedback_enable' => variable_get('fivestar_feedback_'. $object->type, 1),
    'labels_enable' => variable_get('fivestar_labels_enable_'. $object->type, 1),
    'labels' => variable_get('fivestar_labels_'. $object->type, array()),
  );

  return fivestar_custom_widget($form_state, $values, $settings);
}

print drupal_get_form('custom_fivestar_widget', $object);

?>
```

This prints me the widget, I believe using my score. However the text display is all wrong, as is the average score. And it gives everything a permanent 10 stars. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can reproduce fivestar_form function in fivestar.module. See there $settings variable.
So just copy inner of this function, remove some variables checking and set manually some variables. In $settings array set to 'tag' value as you want.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wasn't able to get this to work, I edited my question with my attempt.

Comment: ah, forgot about:
create function of your code, and call in this manner:
print drupal_get_form('yourformfunction', $object, etc variables);
I think, also theming fivestar form will useful...

Comment: I'm sorry... I have no idea what you mean. Could you please please be more specific. I'm totally lost, especially where you put variables. What params do I need in both the function and the drupal get form. Also is it alright to replace the content_type and id, I think they might've not been what I thought they meant. Thanks. Is content_type the type of content, or it user/node/etc. I'm so lost, please help. Thanks!

Comment: etc = some variables, if you don't want pass them (for more dynamic behaviour), you can miss these...

Comment: Well then what do you put into the params for my function? Just yourformfunction($object) ?